# Testing Blackberry apps on physical device using Eclipse on Mac Osx 64 bit

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to test my blackberry application on my blackberry device. I'm getting this error :

Cannot find RIMUsbJni.dll. Without this dll the IDE cannot connect to USB enabled handhelds.

I'm using Eclipse with Blackberry Java Plugin on Mac Osx 64 bit.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my system, that file exists at the location:

> ./Developer-old/Applications/BlackBerry/Indigo-1.5.2/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/198/1/.cp/RIMUsbJni.dll

Of course, `/Developer-old/Applications/` just happens to be the root directory where I chose to install it.  That's going to be different for you.

However, I find it [hard to believe that this file should actually be used on a Mac machine](https://superuser.com/a/228310/173252):

```sh
$ cd /Developer-old/Applications/BlackBerry/Indigo-1.5.2/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/198/1/.cp/
$ file RIMUsbJni.dll 
RIMUsbJni.dll: PE32 executable for MS Windows (DLL) (GUI) Intel 80386 32-bit
```

I think it's just distributed in the plugin as an artifact of the toolkit for Windows users.

I can't remember, since it's been a while since I configured my Mac for BlackBerry development, but I think this error might be triggered if you don't have the proper Mac BlackBerry USB drivers.

You might try installing the [BlackBerry Desktop Software for OS X (US link)](http://us.blackberry.com/software/desktop/desktop-mac.html), and make sure that you can communicate with your device using that application.  If that works, and you still get the same error in Eclipse, I'd try reinstalling [the newest BlackBerry Eclipse Plugin bundle](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/downloads/fetch/BlackBerry_JDE_PluginFull_2.0.0_indigo.zip).

Also, [see this BlackBerry link](http://us.blackberry.com/sites/developers/resources/macdebug.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Mac OS X Lion.

I solved it by installing BlackBerry Desktop Software and replacing Eclipse Mac OS X 64 Bit with Eclipse Mac OS X 32 Bit.